# Classic ASP ADO simple code error

Tags: asp-classic, ado

I have a one liner classic ASP server side code that is failing.

```
...
result = rs(0)
```

That is throwing a HTTP 500.100 - Internal Error and I cannot figure it out. I feel like the dumbest web programmer in the universe at the moment.
I have introduced error checking as in:

```
...
On Error Resume Next
result = rs(0)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    ...
End If
```

and the HTTP error still result!

If I run the actual query in MS SQL Server Management Studio I get the expected result (1 row, 1 column result) so it is not the SQL. If I change the code to:

```
result = rs(1)
```

the On Error Resume Next code picks up the error as "#3265: Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal."

If I hard code to:

```
result = 10.0
```

I get no error.

Also prior to this one line of code I first check for an existing data row as in:

```
If Not rs.EOF Then       
   result = rs(0)        
End If
```

So I can rule out there not being any data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gosh, no wonder I could not find the answer as I had already concluded to eliminate the possible area of concern the DAM SQL!

The precision on the column in question was numeric(19,6) which VBScript could not handle so I casted it to float and all is well.

Comment: That was what I was going to suggest, nice to see you found it yourself. :)